# Aligning two elements from different divs

Tags: jquery, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

At my internship I have been asked to align a buttom on the website with the text next to it, but the button and text are in two different divs.
[Paint Mock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf36H.png)

- The code is used multiple places
- The image defines the height of the container
- The image and text will not always be same lenght and height

My solution uses jQuery to calculate the button location, but i had to opt. for "window load" instead of "document ready" because of image height. This causes the button to move after everything else is settled. Which is ok, but not totally satisfactory. Changing the html will cause a plethora of other issues with mobile viewing.

Is there something inbetween window load and document ready?

Is there a some css hack that i don't know off?

Or any other sugestions would be very much appreciated.

html:

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus ut, fuga perspiciatis minima ipsam est nam dignissimos, dolorum officia sit, molestias, nostrum culpa quaerat veniam minus. Repellat quibusdam, ducimus eum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <a href="google.com">
          My button
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    let button = $(".button");
  let divHeight = $(".first").outerHeight(true);
  let textHeight = $(".text").outerHeight(true);
  
  let top = divHeight / 2 + textHeight / 2;
    button.css("top", top);
})
```

css:

```
.body {
  width: 800px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  
  .first, .second {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .text {
    padding: 60px;
  }
  
}

.button {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 740px;
  a {
    color: white;
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're currently attempting to work with? What's the HTML? What's your JavaScript? Without code this is just asking us to take shots in the dark and guess at what your DOM structure might be.

Comment: Can you please include your HTML markup and necessary CSS + JS for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It gives us a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Added  quick "fiddle" of my code

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole thing in the `main-container` `div` and use `flex`. See the example I put below. I hope this answers your question.

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div>image here</div>
  <div>text here</div>
</div>
```